# Taxonomies starting with a hyphen (minus) to assign B.C. dates to a post

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, archives

I have a date slider to filter posts in the archive by a custom taxonomy that assigns specific years to each post. I would also like to assign B.C. dates to some posts. I figured this would work best by putting a minus in front of the numbers, however wordpress automatically deletes the minus. Does anyone have an idea how I can prevent this or how I could solve this differently?

Comment: Nobody was making blog posts 2000 years ago, so I suspect that the post date is not the appropriate field for whatever it is you're trying to do. Are you trying to use the post date field to date events?

Comment: I use a custom post type for historical events. As I wrote, I use a custom taxonomy for my date slider. @JacobPeattie

Comment: How specific are you with the dates? Are there a lot of things from the same years? If so, and if you want to group them together, I could see how a taxonomy would be helpful. Perhaps include B.C. in the names rather than negative numbers? Another possibility would be to use post meta data; if you don't need the features of a taxonomy, I think it would simplify things significantly.

Comment: To include B.C. in the name is unfortunately not an option, since the date slider is supposed to be chrononlogical. So e.g. from 1000 B.C. to 2022. If I insert B.C. in the name the date slider would start at zero and in between the B.C. dates would appear, because it is sorted alphabetically. Since some events last for decades, it is easiest to use a taxonomy because I can insert a comma separated list of years there. If I put the years all in a post meta field, the date slider interprets that as only one year, the first in the list. So I think a taxonomy is actually the best solution.